# Object to Json and back

Tags: c++, json, c++builder

I am trying to convert an object to Json string. I see an `TJson::ObjectToJsonString()` which seems to meet the needs but it doesn't seem to work. I have the exact code in Delphi, works with no problem. So evidently something more need to be done on the C++ side.

```
class TData : public TObject
{
private:
  String FName;
public:
__property String Name = {read=FName, write=FName};
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Implementation...

```
  TData *data = new TData();

  data->Name = "A Test Name";

  mmMessage->Lines->Add(TJson::ObjectToJsonString(data));
```

I get the output `{}`

Comment: Please present your [MCVE]. At the moment, the 'C' and 'V' bits are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectToJsonObject()` ignores properties, it only marshals fields, and it is smart enough to strip a leading `F` from field names. That is why your `FName` field is marshaled as `Name` in your Delphi code.  See [Convert an object instance into a JSON string and making use of custom attributes](https://flixengineering.com/archives/139), which covers this topic in more details (it is geared towards Delphi, but it applies to C++Builder as well).

Since your `Name` property is fairly useless as-is, you may as well make `Name` be a public field instead of a property:

```
class TData : public TObject
{
public:
  String Name;
};
```

Also make sure your project is setup to generate RTTI for your `TData` class.  Try marking it with `__declspec(delphirtti)`, for instance:

```
class __declspec(delphirtti) TData : public TObject
{
public:
  String Name;
};
```

And make sure you are not explicitly disabling RTTI via [`#pragma explicit_rtti`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pragma_explicit_rtti).

Comment: Thanks! RTTI was the answer. I also made RTTI for private `#pragma explicit_rtti fields(private)`. Now I get the output. FYI, I am just playing around before doing the actual implementation. So yes, they have to be properties.

Comment: @MathewJoy Do you also convert JSON to object? I tried, but couldn't get it o work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025516/use-delphi-serialization-via-json-with-c